# How can I find the file extension of the currently running code?

Tags: matlab, reflection, file-extension

MATLAB provides the [`mfilename`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mfilename.html) function. It returns the name of the file where the function was invoked, but unfortunately, it returns the file name without the [extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension).

So for example, if we have a file called `myfile.m` and we call `mfilename` inside the file, it will return the string `'myfile'` but not `'myfile.m'`

I also had a look at the [`fileparts`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html) function but it is not useful either because it only parses the string that you provide.

I am developing a piece of code has a different behavior based on the file extension. So for instance, it needs to know whether the extension of the file is `.m` or `.p` at [run time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_time_(program_lifecycle_phase)).

You can check the list of extensions associated with MATLAB [here](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/mathworks-file-extensions.html).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Looking at the docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstack.html), it seems like you can get the information you need from the `dbstack` command, it will take some minor additional processing though.

```
[ST, I] = dbstack('-completenames', 1)

ST = 

    file: 'C:\myProject\myfile.m'
    name: 'myfile'
    line: 2
```

Comment: `[ST, I] = dbstack('-completenames')` without `1` worked for me. Then I process `ST.file` with `fileparts` to get the file extension. Thanks a lot.